# Why my event listener won't last after one event when using Promise in ES6?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have following code (a simple one):

**Code:**

```js
var myPromise = new Promise(function(success, error) {
  document.getElementById("success").addEventListener("click", function() {
    success({
      msg: "This is success",
      code: 100
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("error").addEventListener("click", function() {
    error({
      msg: "This is error",
      code: 10
    });
  });
});
console.log("Hello");
myPromise.then(function(content) {
  console.log(content.msg);
});

myPromise.catch(function(content) {
  console.log(content.code);
});
```

```html
<button id="success">Success</button>
<button id="error">Error</button>
```

Clicking on either two buttons **for first time** will **either log** `This is success` or `10`.

Why clicking on either two button for second, third, and subsequent times **will not log anything** in console window? why **the event listener seems to be suddenly gone?**

FYI: I'm currently experimenting with **Promise in ES6** to understand how it works.

Thank You.

Comment: Adding the event listeners inside the promise is a bad idea. Since everytime you click the button, you overwrite your own handlers, so it doesn't work the next time. You should only add new handlers if the elements those handlers are atatched to, disappear.

Comment: A promise can be resolved/rejected only once after that the state change will not have any impact

Comment: @Shilly initialisation is happening only once. OP is trying to `resolve/reject` promise more than ones

Comment: So turn the logic around. Add one handler for each button and have it resolve a promise you created before. Each handler should create a new promise if the prev one has been settled.

Comment: Once the promise is resolved or rejected, it's finished and won't respond to any subsequent calls to `success` or `error` in your event handlers.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wrongly assumed this would be part of a function that gets called multiple times, else I couldn't make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EventListener is present only the Error/Success function won't be called again. I added an `console.info` - Statement to show that the EventListener are being called.

```js
var myPromise = new Promise(function(success, error) {
  document.getElementById("success").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.info("called success" );
    success({
      msg: "This is success",
      code: 100
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("error").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.info("called error" );
    error({
      msg: "This is error",
      code: 10
    });
  });
});
console.log("Hello");
myPromise.then(function(content) {
  console.log(content.msg);
});

myPromise.catch(function(content) {
  console.log(content.code);
});
```

```html
<button id="success">Success</button>
<button id="error">Error</button>
```

Comment: Alright, alright, alright. Nice one, now I understand the cause and more over the event listener still functioning well. Thanks